# Does Python intern strings?

Tags: python, memoization, string-interning

In Java, explicitly declared Strings are interned by the JVM, so that subsequent declarations of the same String results in two pointers to the same String instance, rather than two separate (but identical) Strings.

For example:

```
public String baz() {
    String a = "astring";
    return a;
}

public String bar() {
    String b = "astring"
    return b;
}

public void main() {
    String a = baz()
    String b = bar()
    assert(a == b) // passes
}
```

My question is, does CPython (or any other Python runtime) do the same thing for strings? For example, if I have some class:

```
class example():
    def __init__():
        self._inst = 'instance'
```

And create 10 instances of this class, will each one of them have an instance variable referring to the same string in memory, or will I end up with 10 separate strings?

Comment: Closely related: [About the changing id of a Python immutable string](//stackoverflow.com/a/24245514)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called interning, and yes, Python does do this to some extent, for shorter strings created as string literals. See [About the changing id of an immutable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string) for some discussion.

Interning is runtime dependent, there is no standard for it. Interning is always a trade-off between memory use and the cost of checking if you are creating the same string. There is the [`sys.intern()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern) to force the issue if you are so inclined, which documents *some* of the interning Python does for you automatically:

> Normally, the names used in Python programs are automatically interned, and the dictionaries used to hold module, class or instance attributes have interned keys.

Note that Python 2 the `intern()` function used to be a built-in, no import necessary.

Comment: Note that the `intern` built-in appears to have been removed in Python 3.  I don't feel like digging up exactly which version right now.

Comment: @zwol: 3.0. I'll see if I can find the motivation, probably in a PEP somewhere.

Comment: @zwol: it was moved to the `sys` module.

Answer (score 4):

A fairly easy way to tell is by using `id()`. However as @MartijnPieters mentions, this is runtime dependent.

```
class example():

    def __init__(self):
        self._inst = 'instance'

for i in xrange(10):
    print id(example()._inst)
```

Answer (score 4):

Some strings are interned in python. As the python code compiled, identifiers are interned e.g. variable names, function names, class names.

Strings that meet identifier rules which are starts with underscore or string and contains only underscore, string and number, are interned:

```
a="hello"
b="hello"
```

Since strings are immutable python shares the memory references here and

```
a is b ===> True
```

But if we had

```
a="hello world"
b="hello world"
```

since "hello world" does not meet the identifier rules, a and b are not interned.

```
a is b  ===> False
```

You can intern those with `sys.intern()`. use this method if you have a lot of string repetition in your code.

```
a=sys.intern("hello world")
b=sys.intern("hello world")
```

now
a is b ===> True

Comment: *"Strings that meet identifier rules which are starts with underscore or **string** and contains only underscore, **string** and number, are interned"* -- I think *alphabetic character* (or something similar) might be better word choice, instead of *string*, since technically `" "` is a *string* and based on the rules `"hello world"` is made up of only *strings* so, in contradiction to the rest of your answer, it should be interned. I do like this answer, since your examples show rather than describe the process/outcome.

Answer (score 3):

- All length 0 and length 1 strings are interned.
- Strings are interned at compile time ('wtf' will be interned but ''.join(['w', 't', 'f'] will not be interned)
- Strings that are not composed of ASCII letters, digits or underscores, are not interned. This explains why 'wtf!' was not interned due to !.

https://www.codementor.io/satwikkansal/do-you-really-think-you-know-strings-in-python-fnxh8mtha

The above article explains the string interning in python. There are some exceptions which are defined clearly in the article.