# Compare two Python strings with hyphen/dash

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, special-characters

I am trying to compare to strings in Python and noticed that when a dash/hyphen is present in the string it will not equate identical strings. For example:

```
>>>teststring = 'newstring'
>>>teststring is 'newstring'
True
```

Then, if I add a dash

```
>>>teststring = 'new-string'
>>>teststring is 'new-string'
False
```

Why is that the case, and what would be the best way to compare strings with dashes?

Comment: Test for *equality*, not identity. Use `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should never use `is` to compare equality anyway. `is` tests for identity. Use `==`.

Frankly I don't know why `'newstring' is 'newstring'`. I'm sure it varies based on your Python implementation as it seems like a memory-saving cache to re-use short strings.

However:

```
teststring = 'newstring'
teststring == 'newstring' # True

nextstring = 'new-string'
nextstring == 'new-string' # True
```

basically all `is` does is test `id`s to make sure they're identical.

```
id('new-string') # 48441808
id('new-string') # 48435352
# These change
id('newstring') # 48441728
id('newstring') # 48441728
# These don't, and I don't know why.
```

Comment: See [About the changing id of a Python immutable string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24245514) for why `is` works *sometimes*.

Comment: From my answer there: *[T]he Python compiler will also intern any Python string stored as a constant, provided it is a valid identifier. The Python code object factory function PyCode_New will intern any string object that contains only letters, digits or an underscore*.

Comment: Here's a deeper dive in what get's interned by default: http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `is` for string comparison. Is checks if both objects are same. You should use equality operator `==` here. That compares the values of objects, rather than ids of objects.

In this case, looks like Python is doing some object optimizations for string objects and hence the behavior.

```
>>> teststring = 'newstring'
>>> id(teststring)
4329009776
>>> id('newstring')
4329009776
>>> teststring = 'new-string'
>>> id(teststring)
4329009840
>>> id('new-string')
4329009776
>>> teststring == 'new-string'
True
>>> teststring is 'new-string'
False
```

Comment: See [About the changing id of a Python immutable string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24245514) about when Python interns strings (and identity tests work).

Comment: Makes sense. So this is similar to what python does with 0-255 integer objects, which are always present in the memory all the time. Python never creates new objects for these ints, just adds ref counts as and when needed.

Comment: Indeed. It is an implementation detail however, not something your code should rely on.