# Different storage position of equal strings with special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new at python and I'm currently exploring some of its core functionalities.

Could you explain me why the following example always return false in case of a string with special characters:

```
>>> a="x"
>>> b="x"
>>> a is b
True
>>> a="xxx"
>>> b="xxx"
>>> a is b
True
>>> a="xü"
>>> b="xü"
>>> a is b
False
>>> a="ü"
>>> b="ü"
>>> a is b
True
>>> #strange: with one special character it works as expected
```

I understand that the storage positions are different for strings with special characters on each assignment, I already checked it with the id() function but for which reason python handles strings in this unconsistent way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python (the reference implementation at least) has a cache for small integers and strings. I guess unicode strings outside the ASCII range are bigger than the cache threshold (internally unicode is stored using 16 or 32 bit wide characters, [UCS-2 or UCS-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set)) and so they are not cached.

[edit]

Found a more complete answer at: [About the changing id of a Python immutable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string)

Se also: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/

Comment: i will edit my question, why is a="xxxxxx" b="xxxxxx" a is b still true?

Comment: is this somewhere documented?

Comment: Yes, it is documented, I'm looking for the reference to check the sizes involved.

Answer (score 0):

With is you're not testing equality between strings, you're testing equality between objects which is resolved through pointers. So your code:

```
>>> a="x"
>>> b="x"
>>> a is b
True
```

is not asking "are a and b the same character?", its asking "are a and b the same object?". Since there's a small object cache (for small integers and one byte strings, as has been said before), the answer is "yes, both variables refer to the same object in memory, the x character small object".

When you work with an object that is not eligible for the cache, as in:

```
>>> a="xü"
>>> b="xü"
>>> a is b
False
```

what is going on is that a and b now refer to different objects in memory, so the is operator resolves to false (a and b do not point to the same object!).

If the idea is comparing strings, you should use the == operator instead of is.

Comment: `>>> a="xxx"
>>> b="xxx"
>>> a is b
True`
What about this?

Comment: In my tests, strings with ASCII characters up to 20 chars in length evaluate to the same result using is. That would be the cache working to avoid creating a new object for a string that is cacheable. YMMV, I work with a Windows 8 64 bit Python 2.7.6 64 bit.

Comment: Be aware that GC may behave in distinct ways if your test is running on the REPL or as a script.