# Is the 'is' keyword in Python the same as the === keyword in JS?

Tags: javascript, python, comparison

I saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1) and now I'm curious. How does the `is` operator behave in python in comparison to the === sign in JS?

Comment: How is that the same question? It makes no mention of JS anywhere, and while I know the difference between `is` and ==, I want to know how it relates to `===`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are not the same. `is` in Python checks if two objects have the same `id` in Python, ie. they are the same, even in memory. Something you can do to check is this:

```
>>> a='foo'
>>> a is 'foo'
True
>>> id(a)
44434088
>>> id('foo')
44434088
>>> a=[1]
>>> a is [1]
False
>>> id(a)
45789792
>>> id([1])
4469824
```

Comment: FWIW, I think that `id(a)` and `id('foo')` being the same is something that frequently confuses people when they're trying to understand identity in python.  The fact that `'foo'` is interned by the interpreter is not really an entry level python topic :-)

Comment: So, is it like a hash of the object? How are `id` values assigned?

Comment: @Ares As in `is` will only return true if it's the comparing the exact same object in memory.

Comment: Yeah, but `'foo'` and `a` are clearly *not* the same object, so why does their comparison return true?

Comment: @mgilson, I learned that in the textbook that I learned Python from. It *should* be something people learn, but I do concede that it could be considered a little advanced.

Comment: You should also add that the `===` checks if two variables are the same in value and type in JS.

Comment: @Ares -- The id numbers are assigned differently for different python implementations.  Cpython (the reference implementation that most people have) uses the object's memory address.

Comment: @andybeli No they should not, that would be noise.

Comment: @mgilson which brings me back to my other point of confusion, if they're by memory address, then why did the check on the string literal return true? They shouldn't have the same memory address, right?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it should not what? Could you be more specific... My statement is correct.

Comment: @andybeli The OP already knows that, they even give a link to the question/answer which states that. There isn't a reason to include it.

Comment: @Ares -- This is what I was pointing out as confusing by my initial comment.  Python holds a cache of strings (as an optimization). Frequently (always?) when you reference a string literal, python will look for it in the cache of interned strings and give you the same one that was previously defined.

Comment: @Ares, see this discussion about the string literals http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string

Comment: That `is` tricky... 

That seems like undesired behavior. Without being able to tell if the string has been cached, there's no way to tell if the `is` operation will actually return true, right?

Comment: @Ares -- Nope, there isn't a good way to tell what `is` on two strings which are equivalent will return.  With that said, it's a pretty niche use-case.  Generally `is` comparisons aren't done on strings (or small integers which are the other common objects that can exhibit this strange behavior).  Equality is generally good enough.  If you really need to do reference checking, it's more common to do that on named sentinel objects (`FOO = object()` rather than `FOO = 'foo'`).

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, the `==` operator will do implicit type conversion when comparing for equality so, for instance, `[] == ""` will return `true`.  The `===` operator is used to check equality without type conversion (`[] === ""` returns false.)

In Python, the `is` keyword checks reference equality.  So `x is y` will only return true if `x` and `y` both point to the same object in memory.  For instance:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
z = x
x is y # False
x is z # True
```

Some gotchas that may result from this are the suggested check for null, `x is None`. `None` always points to the same space in memory, so you can be assured that `x is None` will always return `True` if `x` has a None value (and `False` otherwise).

You may also come across some quirks, like the following:

```
x = 1
y = 1
x is y # True
```

The above is a result of a non-standard behaviour in CPython (the Python interpreter you're probably using) where small integers are all assigned to specific objects when the program starts up.  You can check that this doesn't work for larger numbers:

```
x = 1000
y = 1000
x is y # False
```

Unless you're checking for `None` or if you specifically want to make sure two variables are pointing to the same location in memory, you should use `==` instead of `is`.

Answer (score 1):

No. `is` in Python is seemingly much *stricter* than `===` in JS.

In JS:

> For value types (numbers): `a === b` returns true if a and b have the
>   same value and are of the same type
>
> For reference types: `a === b` returns true if a and b reference the
>   exact same object
>
> For strings: `a === b` returns true if a and b are both strings and
>   contain the exact same characters

---

In Python:

Without contradiction, except `id(obj1)` is the same as `id(obj2)`, both objects are not identical, and `obj1 is obj2` will evaluate to `False`.