# classes with same name in different modules share exact same name string?

Tags: python

Slightly surprising behaviour. Two classes with the same name in different modules share the same name. (Not equality, which is expected, but string object identity! )

I don't support it really matters much, but does anyone know why, and whether there's any potential here for further surprises?

Demo (with `a/a.py` and `b/b.py` and empty `__init__.py` in `a/` and `b/`)

```
>>> from a import a
>>> from b import b
>>> ta = a.Test()
>>> tb = b.Test()
>>> ta.__class__.__name__
'Test'
>>> tb.__class__.__name__
'Test'
>>> tb.__class__.__name__ is ta.__class__.__name__  # unexpected
True

>>> ta.__class__
<class 'a.a.Test'>
>>> tb.__class__
<class 'b.b.Test'>
```

Comment: *"the names used in Python programs are automatically interned"* https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern

Comment: All Python strings are immutable, so any interning of strings is totally safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of the CPython interpreter.

It *interns* identifier strings; only one copy is created for source code strings, and re-used everywhere the exact same string value appears. This makes dictionary containment tests faster (by trying pointer comparisons first).

You can do this for your own strings with the [`sys.intern()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern), which helpfully notes:

> Normally, the names used in Python programs are automatically interned, and the dictionaries used to hold module, class or instance attributes have interned keys.

Also see [About the changing id of a Python immutable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string)

Comment: Thanks. Google found this, which seems informative: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mh0bU6NXrBgC&pg=PA505&lpg=PA505&dq=python+interns+identifiers&source=bl&ots=XznyDpc1hd&sig=fsNqflJ_l0N_UhlALvrPh3S7ETQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6kYP4udDQAhWlCcAKHTvgD_UQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=python%20interns%20identifiers&f=false

Comment: @nigel222: that information is rather out of date; see the `sys.intern()` documentation I linked to: *Interned strings are not immortal*; the text you have there states they are. They *used* to be, but only until Python 2.3.

Comment: Yes, out of date, but it had a gentler explanation of what the term "interned" meant! Certainly not to be trusted for Python3 internals hacking!

Comment: @nigel222: sorry, my comment does indeed read harsher than I meant it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As youve noted - you can't rely in sting objects being the same - nor in they being different objects. (Unless you explicitly makes references to the same strings, of course).

If you want to compare for the name, just use the `==` object. If yu want to know if the classes are the same, them use the `is` operator with the classes themselves, not with their names.

Comment: Indeed. Use `ta.__class__ is tb.__class__`

Answer (score 0):

In Python everything is object/class. Whatever you write either a class or function, it's type is **type**.

In question you have 2 diff classes a and b. Here these 2 lines create 2 instances of both classes.

```
>>> ta = a.Test()
>>> tb = b.Test()
```

Function **Test** on each object return class **Test**. A class to **__class__** returns object type or **__repr__** of object. And **name** returns **name** of class in form of string. If you want to confirm type this and see type(tb.**class**.**name**). So

`>>> tb.__class__.__name__ is ta.__class__.__name__`

this is returning true as one **str** is **type** of other.