# When are python objects created?

Tags: python, object, garbage-collection, cpython, python-internals

Python's `id()` function returns the unique identifier for an object. So when in my terminal I do something like:

```
>> a = 23
>> id(a)
28487496
```

Now, I know that python keeps track of all the objects created and number of references to that object and when the value reaches 0, the object is garbage collected.

What I want to know is that what happens when I do something like this:

```
>> id(27)
28487498
```

I never created an object with value 27 i.e i never wrote `b=27` still somehow I get a unique identifier for this. Does this mean that an object was created in memory? If yes, even then there should be 0 references to this object and it should have been garbage collected.

**So, when is an Object actually created in Memory ?**

Please let me know if i am wrong somewhere.

Another interesting thing that I just found out is:

```
>> a = 23
>> id(a)
28487496
>> id(20 + 3)
```

28487496

In this case Python remembers the reference to number 23 itself, how does Python do this?

Comment: `b = 27` does **two** things, it creates the object *and* assigns. `27` still creates the object.

Comment: Now, for small integers, there is an exception: those are interned (one copy each is kept around, they are not created a-new, for performance and memory reasons), see ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](//stackoverflow.com/q/306313)

Comment: It is important to note that making an assignment _is not_ what creates an object.

Comment: Integers from -5 to 256 (_Py27_ specific) are cached, so they are singletones, so everytime you access one of them, it won't create a new object, but redirect to one from that cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are created as needed, in different places.

To start, when you write

```
b = 27
```

**two** things happen. The `27` expression is evaluated, resulting in an integer object being pushed onto the stack, and then, as a separate step, the object is assigned to `b`. **Assignment doesn't create objects**.

If you did just this:

```
27
```

The `27` expression is still evaluated. The object would be created<sup>*</sup>, then destroyed again as the reference count drops back to 0 again.

That's needed because you could pass that object to another function:

```
id(27)
```

needs *something* to be passed to the `id()` function. So `27` is added to the stack so you can call the function.

I'll use a mutable object instead of an integer, to illustrate that a new object is created; so instead of `id(27)` I'll use `id([])` and ask the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to show me the bytecode that Python would execute:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('id([])', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (id)
              2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [`BUILD_LIST 0` opcode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_LIST) is used to create the empty list object and push it onto the stack, and [`CALL_FUNCTION 1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) then calls `id` to passing in one value from the stack, which is that list.

I didn't use `id(27)` because *immutable objects* like integers and tuples and such are actually cached with the bytecode that is compiled; these are created when Python compiles the code (or when you load the `.pyc` bytecode cache from disk):

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('id(27)', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (id)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (27)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the [`LOAD_CONST`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_CONST), it loads the data from the `co_consts` structure:

```
>>> compile('id(27)', '', 'exec').co_consts
(27, None)
```

So objects can be created when compiling, or when execuning special opcodes for specific Python syntax.

There are more places:

- There are more opcodes, for creating lists, tuples, dictionaries, sets and strings, for example.
- When you create an instance of a class, `type.__new__` will create an instance object on the heap. So `CustomClass(arg1, arg2)` creates an object with the right type.
- The same applies to all built-in types; `int(somevalue)` creates an integer object on the heap.
- Plenty of built-in functions will create new objects as needed, returning those from calls
- `class`, `def` statements and the `lambda` expression create objects (class objects, functions, and more functions, these are all objects too).

---

<sup>*</sup> Small integers are actually interned; for performance reasons, CPython keeps a single copy each of the integers between -5 and and 256, so these objects are actually created only once, and referenced everywhere you need one. See ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers). For the purposes of this answer I'm ignoring this.

And because they are interned, the result of `20 + 3` returns that single copy and the `id()` will still be the same as if you asked for `id(23)` directly.

There are more implementation details; there are many more. Some string objects are interned (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-an-immutable-string/24245514#24245514)). Code evaluated in the interactive interpreter is compiled one top-level block at a time, but in a script compilation is done per scope instead. Because constants are attached to compiled code objects, that means that there are differences as to when constants are shared. Etc. etc.

The only objects you can rely on not being recreated all the time are explicitly documented in the [datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) as being singletons; `None` being the most prominent of these.

Comment: _"When you create an instance of a class, type.__new__ will create an instance object on the heap."_ - So would it be correct to say that `type.__new__()` is responsible for creating _all_ objects in Python behind the scenes?

Comment: @ChristianDean: it is responsible for all Python-defined types.

Comment: @ChristianDean: For C objects, `type->tp_alloc()` is used.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. I figured there was a difference between the Python and C level.

Comment: @ChristianDean: under the covers, `type.__new__()` (the `type_new` C function) does use `type->tp_alloc()` somewhere, but there is a  lot of minutiae to take care of for Python types.