# Does Python += operator make string mutable?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, mutability

When I try to modify string using += operator, and use id() method to check object's identity, string seems to be mutable. Did someone face with such a weird python behaviour?

```
a = '123'

print id(a)
# 89806008

a += '1'

print id(a)
# 89245728

a += '1'

print id(a)
# 89245728

print a

# '12311'
```

Using  `a = a + '1'` doesnt have the same effect, and change the string id.

Comment: @Tai That question is about general rebinding of a string variable. This here is about the new object having the same memory address, indicating it is the same object.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Got you.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-an-immutable-string has explanation for this question?

Comment: Maybe the interpreter detects that "1231" is no longer used and places "12311" at the same memory location

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were correct about this string being mutable, then adding

```
b = a
```

before your second `a += '1'` should not have any effect on your output.  But it does.

The reason is that because the string `a` had before the "increment" is no longer used anywhere, the id can be re-used.  But by assigning that string to `b`, it now *is* used somewhere, and the new string for `a` can't re-use that id.

Comment: To be clear, this is a CPython specific optimization (it only works reliably in a reference-counted interpreter). You're not supposed to rely on it, per [PEP8's programming recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "For example, do not rely on CPython's efficient implementation of in-place string concatenation for statements in the form `a += b` or `a = a + b`. This optimization is fragile even in CPython (it only works for some types) and isn't present at all in implementations that don't use refcounting."