# How to access an Enum's value directly as a class attribute?

Tags: python, enums

I'm learning how to use `Enum` classes in Python, and have found that whenever I need to access the actual value of the enum, I need to append the `.value` property:

```
from enum import Enum
class Pets(Enum):
    DOG = "Fido"
    CAT = "Kitty"

Pets.DOG # yields Pets.DOG
Pets.DOG.value # yields Fido
```

As an exercise, I'm trying configure my `Enum` class so that I do not need to continually access that `value` property. **My desired behavior is that when I call `Pets.DOG`, I get `Fido` as my value.**

I'm tried to implement this with `__getattr_(cls, item)`:

```
class Pets(Enum):

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(f"__getattr__ called with {item}")
        return getattr(self, item).value

    DOG = "Fido"
    CAT = "Kitty"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    pets = Pets()
    pets.DOG
```

However, I receive a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`, and `item` is a string value of `_value_`. I'm not quite understanding why this behavior is happening - is this built in Python behavior, or because I am using a special class `Enum`?

I did take a look at a similar SO post, but the solutions there were to use another module (`inspect`), or access the `__dict__` or `dir()` and parse it yourself with a combination of conditionals or regex. Is there a better way to access the underlying `Enum`'s value?

Comment: The value is generally arbitrary. If you actually care about the value of the enum, then the odds are you aren't using enums properly in the first place.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on how I am not using it properly?

Comment: Because you're continually accessing the value; you should generally be doing that in relatively few places, right down at the lowest levels of abstraction, and using e.g. `Pets.DOG` elsewhere.

Comment: Your code should just use the singleton `Pets.DOG`. If `Pets.DOG.value` has some data that matters, then you probably don't want an enumeration, actually - you'd want a namespace, or a dataclass, or something else.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. I guess that answers half my question. I’d still be curious to understand why I’m reach a max recursion error here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use the enum class if you want to map attributes to strings. The whole *point* of the `enum` module is to produce a set of singleton objects that represent an enumeration, not strings. From the module documentation:

> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to **unique, constant values**. Within an enumeration, **the members can be compared by identity**, and the enumeration itself can be iterated over.)

*Bold emphasis mine.* Strings are not unique, constant values (I can create more `"Fido"` strings at will) and are not designed to be compared by identity (even though [sometimes, for a subset of strings, you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-an-immutable-string/24245514#24245514)).

Just define your own class with attributes that are strings, directly:

```
class Pets:
    DOG = "Fido"
    CAT = "Kitty"
```

Your infinite recursion error is caused by a misunderstanding on your part as to what that method is used for. Like [all special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup), `object.attr` looks up `__getattr__` on the *object type*, meaning here that your method applies to *instances* of your `Enum` subclass, the `DOG` and `CAT` attributes here, not to the class itself, and interferes with the `EnumMeta` metaclass trying to test for the `_value_` attibute, which is handled by your `__getattr__` method with `self` being the newly-minted `Pets.DOG` instance, and `item` set to `'_value_'`, which then calls `getattr(Pets.DOG, '_value_')`, which calls `__getattr__`, etc.

For your approach to work, you'd have to subclass `EnumMeta` and implement [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) on that subclass (`__getattr__` is only ever called for *missing* attributes). However, take into account that `__getattribute__` is used for *all* attribute access, so you have to take care to check for instances of the current class first:

```
class EnumDirectValueMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __getattribute__(cls, name):
        value = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if isinstance(value, cls):
            value = value.value
        return value

class Pets(Enum, metaclass=EnumDirectValueMeta):
    DOG = "Fido"
    CAT = "Kitty"
```

at which point `Pets.DOG` produces `'Fido'`.

Comment: Thanks. This is painfully obvious now. Just for my own curiosity, how would I debug the recursive error? I know it's coming from `get_attr()` inside my `__get_attr__` call.

Comment: @YuChen: because the `__getattr__` method applies to the enum instances. You'd have to create a custom `enum.EnumMeta` metaclass subclass to override attribute lookup behaviour on the *class*. Because you defined the method, it interferes with the `EnumMeta` class `__new__` implementation, which tries to access the `_value_` attribute on the instances it creates, with `hasattr(enum_member, '_value_')`; `__getattr__(Pets.DOG, '_value_')` calls `getattr(self, '_value_')`, which calls `getattr(self, '_value_')`, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 2):

You said, "My desired behavior is that when I call `Pets.DOG`, I get Fido as my value." Calling `Pets.DOG` really calls `print(repr(Pets.DOG))`, so my proposal is this:

```
class Pets(enum.Enum):
    DOG = "Fido"
    CAT = "Kitty"
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
```

One advantage to this approach is that you can still access the other features of Enum, such as `Pets.DOG.name`

That said, I would prefer to override `__str__` rather than `__repr__` because that achieves your goal of avoid typing `.value`, but leaves intact the ability to see all information about the `Enum` member when using `repr()`.

I bumped into your question when trying to use namedtuples for my values instead of simple strings. In that case, I think `__getattr__` is helpful, and just in case others find this post for a similar use, I am including what worked for me:

```
import enum
import collections

_ = lambda x : x

class XlateEnum(enum.Enum):
    """Enum whose members inherit the attributes of their values, 
        and which applies the assumed function _() for translations. 
    """
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "_value_":
            return enum.Enum.__getattribute__(self, name)
        elif hasattr(self, "_value_") and hasattr(self._value_, name):
                return _(getattr(self._value_, name))
        return enum.Enum.__getattribute__(self, name)
        
    def __setattr__(self, name, new_value):
        if name == "_value_":
            enum.Enum.__setattr__(self, name, new_value)
        elif hasattr(self, "_value_") and hasattr(self._value_, name):
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        else:
            enum.Enum.__setattr__(self, name, new_value)
            
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, "_value_") and hasattr(self._value_, name):
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        else:
            enum.Enum.__delattr__(self, name)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.str if hasattr(self, "str") else _(enum.Enum.__str__(self.value))
    
class Pet(XlateEnum):
    """My pets. 

    Attributes:
        str: A localized str to name the Pet. How the Pet prints.
        my: A string representing what I call instances of this Pet.
        legs: The int number of legs of normal instances of this Pet.
    """
              
    DOG = collections.namedtuple("PetValue", "str my legs")(_("Dog"), "Fido", 4)
    CAT = collections.namedtuple("PetValue", "str my legs")(_("Cat"), "Kitty", 4)  
    
print(Pet.DOG)    # yields "Dog" (or translated string)
print(Pet.DOG.my) # yields "Fido" (which is not designated for translation)
```

Of course, you can remove the `_()` feature. I find `Enum` and `namedtuple` to very useful for constants because it keeps them in proper relationship to each other, and I like to build all of my translation functionality into the constants themselves, so code like this just works:

```
import ipywidgets
ipywidgets.Dropdown(options=Pet)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from `str`, and the enum values will behave as strings in the same way that `bool`s behave as `int`s (essentially every way except `type()` and `repr()`).

```py
class Pets(str, Enum):
    DOG = "Fido"
    CAT = "Kitty"
```

```py
>>> Pets.DOG
<Pets.DOG: 'Fido'>
>>> Pets.DOG == 'Fido'
True
>>> {'Fido': 5}[Pets.DOG]
5
>>> {Pets.DOG: 5}['Fido']
5
```