# are strings in python mutable, if not explain this?

Tags: python, string

I have declared a string "y as hello than tried to change character "h" by "m" using replace method in python and i checked for the type(y): its showing string
but when I googled, its showing strings are immutable... please explain

```
>>> y="hello"

>>> y=y.replace("h","m")

>>> y


'mello'
>>> type(y)

<class 'str'>
```

Comment: You didn't mutate a string.  You reassigned a variable with an entirely new string.

Comment: Try `x = y = 'hello'` and print `x` afterwards and you will see that it still has the value `hello`. If you do the same with a `list` (a mutable value) then you will see any change reflected in `x`, e.g. `x = y = [0, 1, 2]; y[0] = 5; x` -> `[5, 1, 2]`

Comment: @AChampion with an [important caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245514/4799172) about re-used memory locations

Comment: @roganjosh I decided to avoid this with a different approach than `id()`

Comment: @AChampion yeah, I just realised you edited after I typed so my comment isn't relevant to your new comment, but I think it's probably worth keeping the link

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mutate the String, you changed what String `y` pointed to.

`y` originally pointed to `"hello"`, then you ran the line `y=y.replace("h","m")` and caused `y` to instead point to the String `"mello"`. The original String `"hello"` was never mutated, since Strings are indeed immutable.

Comment: but I lost ``` "hello" ```, right?

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking me.

Comment: in your post you make an example with the "hello"

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo Yes. What about it?

Comment: ok, thanks, nevermind, excuse me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, strings are immutable. When you run the line
    y=y.replace("h","m")
you are creating a new string, not changing the first one. The first string can't actually be changed.

Answer (score -1):

String in Python are immutable (cannot change to allow for optimization of using one dictionary for all strings).

For example:

```
>>> y="hello"

>>> y.replace("h","m")
'mello'

>>> y
'hello'
```

When we want to change a string, we can either use bytearray or (often better) - just create a new string. Consider for example the method 'replace'. It did not change the string in the example - but we could assign it's return value.

```
>>> y1 = y.replace("h","m")
>>> y1
'mello'
```

Or even use the same variable y, in which case it will create a new string and overwrite the previous value of y.

```
>>> y = y.replace('h','m')
>>> y
'mello'
```

Which is just like putting a new value alltogether:

```
>>> y = 'a new value'
>>> y
a new value
```

Comment: Strings are _not_ mutable. I don't know what you're trying to say here. You haven't mutated a string in terms of mutable/immutable, you are always creating a new string.

Comment: Nowhere in this answer have you mutated a String. Please be careful when posting things like this. We don't need to confuse the OP more than they already are.

Comment: Wait, is the first paragraph supposed to say "String[s] in Python are **immutable**"? You seem to be saying that they're immutable in the rest of the answer, but you're contradicting the first paragraph.

Comment: yes - sorry, fixed now