# How python memory manage string object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

```
for count in range(5):
    str1 = 'a' * count
    str2 = 'a' * count
    print(id(str1) == id(str2))

Output:
    True
    True
    False
    False
    False
```

> Why we are getting False, Because

```
str1 = 'aaa'
str2 = 'aaa'
print(id(str1) == id(str2)) # True
```

> Anyone explain this python memory behaviour.

Comment: Why does it matter? If you want to test for string equality, use the `==` operator. What happens here is some kind of memory usage optimisation that's probably specific to CPython

Comment: thanks, but which type of memory optimisation CPython is doing, any idea ?

Comment: I'm really curious about this question as well. Since str1 and str2 are different strings, shouldn't they have different ID's? Or because they're pointing to the same thing, they have the same memory address?

Comment: This also happens in integers up to `256`.   
Probably some sort of optimization, not A big deal.

Answer (score 5):

Let us first investigate what `id()` does:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

OK, so, in general, when two names are pointing to the exact same object, they will have the same `id()`.

Why then do we have this?

```
str1 = 'aaa'
str2 = 'aaa'
print(id(str1) == id(str2)) # True
```

That is because, in [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) (the C reference implementation of Python), strings are cached in a hashtable (for performance reasons) and it is cheaper to have `str1` and `str2` to point to the same memory.
Note that this can be done without much unexpected behaviors because strings are immutable in Python.
However, this mechanism is triggered only for strings that [appear in full in the interpreter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/codeobject.c#L57), e.g.:

```
for i in range(5):
    a = eval('"' + 'a' * i + '"')
    b = eval('"' + 'a' * i + '"')
    print(id(a) == id(b), a, b)
```

> ```
> True  
> True a a
> True aa aa
> True aaa aaa
> True aaaa aaaa
> ```

Any mechanism that creates a `str` dynamically within the interpreter (i.e. aside of `eval()`), is outside of this caching, like your example, or:

```
a = 'aaa'
b = a[1:]
c = 'aa'
print(id(b) == id(c))
# False
print(id(b) == id(a[1:]))
# False
```

For further reference, the internal representation of strings in Python is described in more detail in [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/#string-creation).

Comment: This is a very good answer indeed! It may perhaps be worth noting a little bit about references in general in Python (such as the fact that `a = '456'` and `b = '456'` will point to the same pointer, while `a = 456` and `b = 456` will not).

Comment: For `int`s, this is triggered until `256`

Comment: @norok2 I understand the string intern and caching but I still don't fully understand the original loop. Why is it from iteration 3 onwards they evaluate to false?

Comment: @CathalCronin This happens when count is `0` or `1` for which there is shortcircuit and no new string are actually generated

Comment: @norok2 String interning operates on strings of length 20 or less I thought? Is it because its within a loop that this gets shortcircuited to a length of 0 or 1?

Comment: @CathalCronin no, the shortcircuit happens on `s * 0` or `s * 1` for any string, at any point in the code. Instead of generating a dynamic string, those two operations gets a pointer to the empty string and `s` itself, respectively.

Comment: @norok2 Okay, is that explained in the documentation somewhere? Do you have a link that explains that in more detail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24245324/5769463 @CathalCronin in a nutshell: strings are interned at compile time if constant folding happens (the case for length 1 strings) but not for strings created at run time (the others)