# Are fundamental data types in Python Objects too?

Tags: python

I read that everything in Python is an Object i.e. it can contain reference variables and methods. However reference variables also point to Objects.

So let us say I have the following code ->

```
a = "Hello"
```

This creates an Object, but where is "Hello" Stored. We need some fundamental data type that is neither an Object nor a reference variable correct?

Comment: ...but strings are references to other memory?

Comment: That's up to the implementation, e.g. CPython will store some kind of C string or array of chars or bytes under the hood.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe what variable/attribute of the String Object stores "Hello" ? If you look at C, I can see the memory location and read the memory byte by byte to see the "Hello" in ASCII. How do I do that in Python?

Comment: Strings are actually an interesting example in this case, due to [string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-an-immutable-string)

Comment: You *don't* do that in Python. It's a high level language, those things are abstracted away from you so you can focus on other things. If you want to iterate character by character, for example, you just write `for character in a:`, you don't have to care about memory locations, null terminators or whatever else.

Comment: Okay I should not have taken String example. Let me take integer example? There has got to be some attribute that is NOT a reference variable, but a very fundamental C like data type that directly points to the memory location of data. How do we find that in Python?

Comment: Again, you don't. Python puts an arbitrary-precision abstraction over the underlying value the implementation stores in memory. *Everything in Python is an object*, it's up to the specific implementation how to represent those things in memory and that's *not* exposed to you.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe thanks for the edit. Are there good sources to understand the CPython implementation of Python except of course the source code.

Comment: Note resource recommendations are off-topic here, but I've heard good things about Philip Guo's CPython walkthrough: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwyG5wA5gIzgTFj5KgJJ15lxq5Cv6lo_0.