# Hashing numpy object array, how does hashlib see objects' contents and not just pointers?

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api, hashlib

I am wondering, how come hashing e.g. strings in an np object[] produces expected results:

```
>>> hashlib.sha256(np.array(['asdfda'], dtype=object)).hexdigest()
'6cc08fd2542235fe8097c017c20b85350899c81616db8cb59045022663e3cee1'
>>> hashlib.sha256(np.array(['asd'+'fda'], dtype=object)).hexdigest()
'6cc08fd2542235fe8097c017c20b85350899c81616db8cb59045022663e3cee1'
```

That is, the hashing takes into account the actual object value, not a just the pointer value, as stored in the array. (Those strings would definitely have different pointers.)

`hashlib` methods seem to accepting objects supporting some 'buffer API', as not doing so produces `TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required`.

Does that mean that buffer API implementation for numpy's ndarray does not return an array of pointers, but rather somehow an array of strings, or in other words how does `hashlib.hash_algorithm` get to those stored strings of characters?

Comment: I'd suggest that [this](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) is the "some 'buffer API'" that it's required to support. It doesn't really answer what it's doing with the PyObjects but it gives you a clue about where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Those strings would definitely have different pointers.

**Definitely** is a pretty strong claim here. Look what I see just testing that out in a REPL:

```
>>> s = 'asdfda'
>>> s2 = 'asd'+'fda'
>>> s is s2
True
```

However,

```
>>> s3 = s[:2] + s[2:]
>>> s is s3
False
>>>
```

And just as expected, the hash is different:

```
>>> hashlib.sha256(np.array([s],dtype=object)).hexdigest()
'176c63097ace4b6754acdd8e37b861bbe1e33489f52d6bd8df07983ead23c73e'
>>> hashlib.sha256(np.array([s3],dtype=object)).hexdigest()
'478307a1bfb4bf413c7e538cc4bbe02370072b0968a91155a4a838e68477f62e'
>>>
```

Comment: Oh no. I didn't realize string interning was so powerful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245514/3791837

Comment: I believed it because it, in my case, worked :D, i.e. I got the same hash value. The case: my pandas Series had for the same string somehow same pointers, even though it was read from a csv and the strings were on different lines and I did _not_ specify the Series to be of type 'category'. See more at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65012145/3791837

Comment: @Adam probably `pandas.read_csv` interns the strings while it parses the csv. That isn't entirely unusual, for example, `json.load` does the same thing