# Pandas: object type is stored like a category, i.e. equal strings point to same object?

Tags: python, pandas

In the following example, string 'asdf' is stored as the same exact pointer (to a str instance), even though there are two occurences in the dataframe:

**test.csv**

```
asdf,12
dsf,45
asdf,789
```

**python script**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)

np_array_of_1st_column = df[0].to_numpy()

print(df.dtypes)

# getting bytes value of the 1st pointer (to string 'asdf')
print(np_array_of_1st_column[0:1].tobytes())

# .. the 3rd pointer (again to string 'asdf')
print(np_array_of_1st_column[2:3].tobytes())
```

And output:

```
0    object
1     int64
dtype: object
b'\xf0\xe45\x9e\xe9\x7f\x00\x00'
b'\xf0\xe45\x9e\xe9\x7f\x00\x00'
```

The last two lines are the same, the pointers point to the same string instance! Even though the string was read on different lines of the csv file.

I've heard that by using 'category' dtype instead of 'object' you save space (besides other things). But I see that the space is saved already? I'm asking this to know, if it's a sure thing or is guaranteed, given the series is not of a 'category' type.

---

Motivation:

Using type 'category', can make my subsequent analysis (groupby, and enumerating all groups into a list) run out of memory. Really the more dtypes I specify as category, the more memory it somehow consumes.

So without using somehow 'slow and hungry' category type I would like to know, for hashing purposes, that two identical strings in a series are stored as an identical pointer, in the underlying `to_numpy` array (as if I used the category type, that would be that way right?).

Comment: Using `category` does not automatically save space. It only saves space if you have a relatively small amount of unique strings. In the extreme case of having all unique strings, it would *certainly* require more memory.

Comment: Indeed, the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) state this right off the bat: "The categorical data type is useful in the following cases: * A string variable consisting of only a few different values. Converting such a string variable to a categorical variable will save some memory, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-memory)."

Comment: You should **definitely not rely** on your strings being interned. That is an implementation detail of the `pd.read_csv` method, AFAIKT.  This is not some guarantee of `pd.Series` object, e.g. `s = pd.Series(["foo", "foo"[:-1] + 'o']); print(s.map(id))`

Comment: True my string variable does not 'consist of _a few_ different values', but rather a value is repeated _a few_ times. So probably I have to use another hashing method for my string series.