# why same strings in python doesn't have same id?

Tags: python, string

In python I have experienced something that was a little weird for me.

```py
>>> a = "a"
>>> b = "a"
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

But when I choos another string value for `a` and `b` this behaves different.

```py
>>> a = "dlfkgmdflkgd gdflkg dflkg dflkgd fgdfg"
>>> b = "dlfkgmdflkgd gdflkg dflkg dflkgd fgdfg"
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

what is the difference betwee `"a"` and `"dlfkgmdflkgd gdflkg dflkg dflkgd fgdfg"` ?

Comment: There may be something wrong with your interpreter. I just ran it and it worked fine.

Comment: I tested in an online interpreter and it gave `True`.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY07DoAgEET7PcV0uLU1hwE2IBHRqI2nRzSY0NrML5O87TqnNY@lGGgoo8g2p22P@RwM4gHLrUUZDENr1GCZidzzluTnsIhPcxCE19GpwNcxKJI/50Z0D186vvv4wlzKDQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: it's very strang!

Comment: I'm getting the same results as @Amir inside the Command Prompt.

Comment: It works differently in the Python shell. As @Haveaniceday said, it returns `False` in the Command prompt.

Comment: Read about [String Interning](https://medium.com/@bdov_/https-medium-com-bdov-python-objects-part-iii-string-interning-625d3c7319de#c549)

Comment: This is the result of an optimization in the CPython interpreter. [some more details...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24245324/3929826)

Comment: @Justin yes, I've tested the code as a file and get `True`. But in shell I get `False`

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi - Try `a == b`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)

Comment: This isn't strange. Why do you *think* they should have the same id??? Basically, the python runtime is free to optimize various immutable types. All of these are *implementation details* (that shouldn't be relied on), for example, length-1 strings are interned. You shouldn't rely on this, and it should be *surprising* that these would ever have the same id, not the opposite!