# Python multiple inheritance and memory allocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Suppose the following class hierarchy in Python:

```
class O:
    variable = 0


class A(O):
    variable = "abcdef"


class B(O):
    variable = 1.0


class X(A, B):
    pass


x = X()
```

When an instance of X gets created, does Python allocate the memory for each *variable* in the base classes, or only for the resolved *variable*?

Comment: Those are all _class attributes_, so they're created at class definition time and shared between all instances, and 2/3 of them (`0` as a small integer, `"abcdef"` as an identifier-like string - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245514/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/3001761) would be _interned_ by CPython anyway

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't allocate *any* variables when you create an instance of `X`; all of your `variable`s are class attributes, not instance attributes, so they're attached to their respective classes, not to the instance. `X` and instances of `X` would see `variable` with the value from `A` thanks to the order in which it checks base classes for names when the name isn't set on the instance, but all three versions of `variable` would exist.

If you *did* make them instance attributes (assigned to `self.variable` in `__init__` for each class), and used `super()` appropriately to ensure all `__init__`s called, there'd only be one copy of `self.variable` when you were done initializing (which one survived would depend on whether you initialized `self.variable` or called `super().__init__()` first in the various `__init__` implementations). This is because Python doesn't "resolve" names in the way you're thinking; instance attributes are stored by string name on a `dict` under-the-hood, and the last value assigned to that name wins.

The only way to have multiple instance attributes with the "same" name is to make them private, by prefixing them with `__`; in that case, with all three defining `self.__variable`, there'd be a uniquely name-mangled version of `__variable` seen by the methods of each class (and not used by parent or child classes); `X` wouldn't see one at all, but methods it inherited from `A` would see `A`'s version, methods inherited from `B` would see `B`'s version, etc.