# Memory usage when reading lines from a piped subprocess stdout in python

Tags: python, memory, subprocess, popen, ram

I just want to understand what happens in the "background" in terms of memory usage when dealing with a subprocess.Popen() result and reading line by line. Here's a simple example.

Given the following script `test.py` that prints "Hello" then waits 10s and prints "world":

```
import sys
import time
print ("Hello")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(10)
print ("World")
```

Then the following script `test_sub.py` will call as a subprocess 'test.py', redirect the stdout to a pipe and then read it line by line:

```
import subprocess, time, os, sy

cmd = ["python3","test.py"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines = True)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
   print("---" + line.rstrip())
```

In this case my question would be, when I run `test_sub.py` after it does the subprocess call, it will print "Hello" then wait 10s until "world" comes and then print it, **what happens to "Hello" during those 10s of waiting? Does it get stored in memory until `test_sub.py` finishes, or does it get tossed away in the first iteration?**

This may not matter to much for this example, but when dealing with really big files it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens to "Hello" during those 10s of waiting?

The `"Hello"` (in the parent) is available via `line` name until `.readline()` returns the second time i.e., `"Hello"` lives *at the very least* until the output of `print("World")` is read in the parent.

If you mean what happens in the child process then after `sys.stdout.flush()` there is no reason for `"Hello"` object to continue to live but it may e.g., see [Does Python intern strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17679861/4279)

> Does it get stored in memory until test_sub.py finishes, or does it get tossed away in the first iteration?

After `.readline()` returns the second time, `line` refers to `"World"`. What happens with `"Hello"` after that depends on the garbage collection in the specific Python implementation i.e., even if `line` is `"World"`; the object `"Hello"` may continue to live for some time. [Releasing memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455048).

You could set `PYTHONDUMPREFS=1` envvar and run your code using a *debug* `python` build, to see object that are alive when the `python` process exits. For example, consider this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
import time
import sys

def strings():
    yield "hello"
    time.sleep(.5)
    yield "world"
    time.sleep(.5)

def print_line():
    while True:
        time.sleep(.1)
        print('+++', line, file=sys.stderr)

threading.Thread(target=print_line, daemon=True).start()
for line in strings():
    print('---', line)
time.sleep(1)
```

It demonstrates that `line` is not rebound until the second `yield`. 
The output of `PYTHONDUMPREFS=1 ./python . |& grep "'hello'"`
shows that `'hello'` is still alive when `python` exits.