# deep equality vs shallow equality in python?

Tags: python

I read somewhere that the shallow equality for reference type like tuples, lists and strings referes to comparing them to see if they are the same.

For strings and lists the axiom is correct. But for tuple, it is wrong:

```
t1 = (1, 2)
t2 = (1, 2)
print(t1 is t2)
print(t1 == t2)
```

this code outputs True and True.

Can someone please explain why they are the same please.

Comment: I think this is a CPython optimisation for tuples specifically - because it's a tuple literal of integer literals and they're all immutable, the same exact value can be used for both. It's an implementation detail though. Note this isn't "deep" or "shallow" equality - it's equality vs. identity.

Comment: please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660396/why-some-types-of-data-refer-to-the-same-memory-location  '==' if the content same. 'is' if the object refers same memory location.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: a couple things, "deep" and "shallow" equality are not standard terminology in Python. It isn't clear what you are referring to. Also note, there are no "reference types" in Python. Everything in Python is an object, there are no exceptions, and there are no special semantics to keep in mind. There is no "axiom" such as you've described.  the object being referred to by `t1` and `t2` happens to be the same object. Here, the runtime is optimizing something. You shouldn't have expected *anything in particular* for the result of `is` here. This is **crucial to understand**

Comment: Another thing you can do is to use the id() function and print it for both t1 and t2 and you will see its same. Cpython implementation for id is the address of the object.

Comment: Are you saying you get `False` and `True` when you make `t1` and `t2` lists or strings? For lists that's the expected behaviour, but for strings, like others have said, `is` is not meaningful, though FWIW, I get `True` and `True` on my default interpreter.

Comment: @juanpa It looks like they're using "shallow equality" to refer to `is` (i.e. are these two **references** equal; which is actually called *identity* in Python) and "deep equality" to refer to `==` (i.e. are these two **objects** equal; which is just called *equality* in Python). @bib please [edit] to clarify. It'd also help to add where you got these terms from and why you were expecting the tuples to be different objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does `() is ()` return True when `[] is []` and `{} is {}` return False?](/q/38328857/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)