# id() vs `is` operator. Is it safe to compare `id`s? Does the same `id` mean the same object?

Tags: python, identity, identity-operator

How much can I rely on the object's `id()` and its uniqueness in practice? E.g.:

- Does `id(a) == id(b)` mean `a is b` or vice versa? What about the opposite?
- How safe is it to save an `id` somewhere to be used later (e.g. into some registry instead of the object itself)?

<sub>(Written as a proposed canonical in response to [Canonicals for Python: are objects with the same id() the same object, `is` operator, unbound method objects](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373074/canonicals-for-python-are-objects-with-the-same-id-the-same-object-is-oper))</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [`id()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id), an `id` is only guaranteed to be unique

1. for the lifetime of the specific object, and
2. within a specific interpreter instance

As such, **comparing `id`s is not safe unless you also somehow ensure that both objects whose `id`s are taken are still alive at the time of comparison** (and are associated with the same Python interpreter instance, but you need to really try to make that become false).

Which is exactly what `is` does -- which makes comparing `id`s redundant. If you cannot use the `is` syntax for whatever reason, there's always [`operator.is_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator#operator.is_).

---

Now, **whether an object is still alive at the time of comparison is not always obvious** (and sometimes is grossly *non*-obvious):

- **Accessing some attributes** (e.g. [bound methods of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/ids-of-bound-and-unbound-method-objects-sometimes-the-same-for-different-o)) **creates a new object each time.** So, the result's `id` may or may not be the same on each attribute access.

  Example:

  ```
  >>> class C(object): pass
  >>> c=C()
  >>> c.a=1

  >>> c.a is c.a
  True        # same object each time

  >>> c.__init__ is c.__init__
  False       # a different object each time

  # The above two are not the only possible cases.
  # An attribute may be implemented to sometimes return the same object
  # and sometimes a different one:
  @property
  def page(self):
      if check_for_new_version():
          self._page=get_new_version()
      return self._page
  ```
- If an object **is created as a result of calculating an expression and not saved anywhere, it's immediately discarded,**<sup>1</sup> and any object created after that can take up its `id`.

  - This is even true within the same code line. E.g. the result of `id(create_foo()) == id(create_bar())` is undefined.

    Example:

    ```
    >>> id([])     #the list object is discarded when id() returns
    39733320L
    >>> id([])     #a new, unrelated object is created (and discarded, too)
    39733320L      #its id can happen to be the same
    >>> id([[]])
    39733640L      #or not
    >>> id([])
    39733640L      #you never really know
    ```

---

Due to the above safety requirements when comparing `id`s, saving an `id` instead of the object is not very useful because you have to save a reference to the object itself anyway -- to ensure that it stays alive. Neither is there any performance gain: [`is` implementation is as simple as comparing pointers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_operator.c#L691).

---

Finally, as an internal optimization (and implementation detail, so this may differ between implementations and releases), CPython reuses some often-used simple objects of immutable types. As of this writing, that includes [small integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) and [some strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679861/does-python-intern-strings). So even if you got them from different places, their `id`s might coincide.

This does not (technically) violate the above `id()` documentation's uniqueness promises: the reused object stays alive through all the reuses.

This is also not a big deal because whether two variables point to the same object or not is only practical to know if the object is mutable: [if two variables point to the same mutable object, mutating one will (unexpectedly) change the other, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785084/changing-one-list-unexpectedly-changes-another-too). Immutable types don't have that problem, so for them, it doesn't matter if two variables point to two identical objects or to the same one.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Sometimes, this is called "unnamed expression".</sub>