# numpy advanced indexing inaccurate documentation?

Tags: python, numpy

According to the [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

> The definition of advanced indexing means that x[(1,2,3),] is fundamentally different than x[(1,2,3)]. The latter is equivalent to x[1,2,3] which will trigger basic selection while the former will trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this occurs.

and

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a **non-tuple sequence object**, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool), or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer and Boolean.

However in my own testing it appears that even for tupples, if it doesn't have at least one slice object, or one np.newaxis, or one Ellipse object, then it will be triggering advanced indexing

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros(shape=(5,5,5))
arr[(1,2,3)].flags.owndata       # evaluates to True
```

Is this the correct behavior?

Comment: `arr[1,2,3]` is a single  element, a `np.float64` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [5]: arr = np.zeros(shape=(5,5,5))
```

This is basic indexing with a tuple of indices:

```
In [6]: arr[(1,2,3)]
Out[6]: 0.0
In [7]: type(_)
Out[7]: numpy.float64
```

The result is an item, not an array (or view of an array).  It's the same thing as:

```
In [8]: arr[1,2,3]
Out[8]: 0.0
In [9]: type(_)
Out[9]: numpy.float64
```

Scalar numpy items like this always have their own data.  I elaborate on this in my answer to a recent question about `is`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485031/901925