# "is" operation returns false even though two objects have same id

Tags: python, numpy

Two python objects have the same id but "is" operation returns false as shown below:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(2, -1)
c = a.reshape(12, 1)
print("id(c.data)", id(c.data))
print("id(a.data)", id(a.data))

print(c.data is a.data)
print(id(c.data) == id(a.data))
```

Here is the actual output:

```
id(c.data) 241233112
id(a.data) 241233112
False
True
```

My question is... why "c.data is a.data" returns false even though they point to the same ID, thus pointing to the same object? I thought that they point to the same object if they have same ID or am I wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Even though the `id` is the same, the memory addresses are different, try `print(c.data)` and `print(a.data)`

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, but I can't find any...

Comment: @C.Nivs They don't even necessarily have different memory addresses (something which Python doesn't expose). Whatever memory was used for the first may have been reused for the second.

Comment: @chepner you're right, on subsequent calls the memory addresses are re-used

Comment: @C.Nivs Don't think of it in terms of memory addresses. How memory is managed is *completely* implementation dependent. All you know for sure is that two objects that overlap in time will not have the same id.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, that's okay a good question(though asked before) can sometimes be resurrected for a fruitful discussion

Comment: @chepner that clears that up immensely. So if I were to store an object as a variable in memory, that `id` is taken and won't be assigned to any other variable unless I pass a reference from that object to the other (if I can do that)

Comment: @C.Nivs no, *ids do not belong to variables*. They belong to *objects*. Many variables can reference the same object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think my terminology is off, that's what I meant by the `id` won't be re-used unless the reference is shared between two variables, in which case I think "re-used" is the wrong term here. thanks for the clarification

Comment: References aren't shared between two variables; each variable *is* a reference to the object it refers to.

Comment: @C.Nivs yes, you need to understand, Python variables are not like C variables. The best way is to think of a Python variable as *literally a key in a dict*. This is actually true for the global scope, but modern python optimizes local scopes as essentially arrays/symbol tables. In any case, just as you can have 100 references to the same *object* in a dict, a variable can reference the same object, or a different object, and the ID belongs to the object, not the variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga As I'm not a C programmer, I don't think I was conflating the two, just trying to get my understanding straight here. Again, I think semantically I'm just not using the terminology right, I still have a ton to learn in this space. The reason I said *sharing a reference* is in regard to referencing a mutable object like if I assigned `a = some_list; b = a`, `b` and `a` are different *variables* but they reference the same object

Comment: @C.Nivs sure, but note, mutable/immutable is irrelevant. *The semantics of python assignment are exactly the same regardless of type*. `a = some_tuple; b = a` both `a` and `b` refer to the same object, which happens to be immutable.

Comment: @C.Nivs Perhaps you should read Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [id() vs `is` operator. Is it safe to compare `id`s? Does the same `id` mean the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268343/id-vs-is-operator-is-it-safe-to-compare-ids-does-the-same-id-mean-the), but as per my long-running dialog with @ivan-pozdeev over there, that question needs tons more real-world examples in Python where objects (/attributes/views) we might expect are the same or different, are actually the opposite, or implementation-dependent.

Comment: **What were you intending to test with `is` operator on the `.data` attribute?** `a is c` gives False, telling you the *arrays* themselves are different (different dimensions, in this particular case). But they can be built on the same underlying data, hence `a.data` view gives the same as `c.data`. Are you just poking at numpy's memory internals, or were you trying to test some programming property, if so what? (Don't use `is` to test numerical equality, for example)

Comment: @PM2Ring Just finished reading, thanks for the link, it really put the things that juanpa.arrivillaga and chepner were explaining into perspective

Answer (score 17):

`a.data` and `c.data` both produce a *transient* object, with no reference to it. As such, both are immediately garbage-collected. The same id can be used for both.

In your first `if` statement, the objects have to co-exist while `is` checks if they are identical, which they are not.

In the second `if` statement, each object is released as soon as `id` returns its id.

If you save references to both objects, keeping them alive, you can see they are not the same object.

```
r0 = a.data
r1 = c.data
assert r0 is not r1
```

Comment: what is confusing is the fact that `data` looks like an attribute, but is probably a property

Comment: In my tests, the id's are different in the first run, but change to become the __same__ on subsequent runs.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so would that mean that the object itself is only returned when a getter is called, and the property is not actually stored in the class? I'm not quite familiar with the differences between a property vs attribute

Comment: a property is a method disguised as an attribute. So it can return a discardable integer, object, whatever.

Comment: Thank you all! Coming from C/C++, I was just looking for a way to check if two different pointers point  to the same object.  So I should use "is operator" to compare if check if two pointers point to the same object. id() can return the same string since it can be re-used for transient objects. Thanks

Comment: Say "names" rather than pointers; it's best to understand how variables work in Python rather than try to apply any understanding you bring from another language. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a good overview. `is` (and `id`) gets used far less often than you might expect.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [62]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(2,-1) 
    ...: c = a.reshape(12,1)
```

`.data` returns a `memoryview` object. `id` just gives the id of that object; it's not the value of the object, or any indication of where `a` databuffer is located.

```
In [63]: a.data                                                                 
Out[63]: <memory at 0x7f672d1101f8>
In [64]: c.data                                                                 
Out[64]: <memory at 0x7f672d1103a8>
In [65]: type(a.data)                                                           
Out[65]: memoryview
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview

If you want to verify that `a` and `c` share a data buffer, I find the `__array_interface__` to be a better tool.

```
In [66]: a.__array_interface__['data']                                          
Out[66]: (50988640, False)
In [67]: c.__array_interface__['data']                                          
Out[67]: (50988640, False)
```

It even shows the offset produced by slicing - here 24 bytes, 3*8

```
In [68]: c[3:].__array_interface__['data']                                      
Out[68]: (50988664, False)
```

---

I haven't seen much use of `a.data`.  It can be used as the `buffer` object when creating a new array with `ndarray`:

```
In [70]: d = np.ndarray((2,6), dtype=a.dtype, buffer=a.data)                    
In [71]: d                                                                      
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [72]: d.__array_interface__['data']                                          
Out[72]: (50988640, False)
```

But normally we create new arrays with shared memory with slicing or `np.array` (copy=False).