# Why isn't `str(1) is '1'` `True` in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-interning

I'm not asking about the difference between `==` and `is` operators! I am asking about **interning** or something..!

In Python 3.9.1,

```
>>> str(1) is '1'
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
False
>>> '1' is '1'
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
True
```

I found out that characters which match [a-zA-Z0-9_] are interned in Python. I understand why `'1' is '1'`. Python stores a character `'1'` somewhere in the memory internally and refers to it whenever '1' is called. And `str(1)` returns `'1'`, and I think, it should refers to the same address as other literal `'1'`s. Shouldn't `str(1) is '1'` also be `True`?

Comment: All string literals are interned, i.e. `"foobar!?" is "foobar!?"` is also `True`. `str(1)` is not a _literal_ therefore it is not interned.

Comment: Nope, ```is``` is used to compare ```references``` rather than the contents of the objects. If you have two different ```string``` objects, having the same contents. ```is``` will give false, but ```==``` will give true. ```is``` has nothing special to do with types.

Comment: @MHP That's incorrect/missing information.

Comment: [python-string-interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)

Comment: @Muhteva The OP is asking about interning, they seem to know the difference between `is` and `==`. Python makes that difference a bit vague in some cases because of compiler optimisations. For example after `a = "12"` and `b = "1" + "2"`, `a is b` will (surprisingly) return `True`.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point out that argument of @MHP is false.

Comment: @Selcuk - good example. its the compiler that figures out "1" + "2" and makes the string literal that is interned.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679861/does-python-intern-strings

Comment: Notes on interning in the `intern` function docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern

Comment: "Shouldn't str(1) is '1' also be True?" No, there is no reason for you to expect that. Any interning is an implementation detail anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is` checks for references, not content. Also, `str(1)` is not a literal therefore it is not interned.

But `'1'` is interned because it's directly a string. Whereas `str(1)` goes through a process to become a string. As you can see:

```
>>> a = '1'
>>> b = str(1)
>>> a
'1'
>>> b
'1'
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a)
1603954028784
>>> id(b)
1604083776304
>>>
```

So the way to make them both interned is with `sys.intern`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = '1'
>>> b = str(1)
>>> a is b
False
>>> a is sys.intern(b)
True
>>>
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern):

> Enter *string* in the table of “interned” strings and return the
> interned string – which is *string* itself or a copy. Interning strings
> is useful to gain a little performance on dictionary lookup – if the
> keys in a dictionary are interned, and the lookup key is interned, the
> key comparisons (after hashing) can be done by a pointer compare
> instead of a string compare. Normally, the names used in Python
> programs are automatically interned, and the dictionaries used to hold
> module, class or instance attributes have interned keys.
>
> Interned strings are not immortal; you must keep a reference to the
> return value of `intern()` around to benefit from it.

*Note that in Python 2 `intern()` was a built-in keyword, but now in python 3 it was merged into the `sys` module to become `sys.intern`*

Comment: `i = 1; '012'[i] is '1'` also goes through a process but gives me `True`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Well yes it's because indexing would feed the code into the `__getitem__` magic method where the str class controls, same with `+`

Comment: Same with what `+`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode It goes into the `__add__` magic method

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode It still would make it remain in the same class instance so the references would be equivalent, whereas calling like `str(1)` would start a completely new class instance.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode if you're doing `'1' + '1'` that actually gets constant-folded to `'11'` during bytecode compilation.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode as for indexing, I assume that's a specifically implemented behaviour (as single chars from strings would usually be used a lot): it happens for indexing and single-char slices, but not for slices of length 2+.

Comment: @Masklinn Yes, I know about that `+` during compilation. If that's what U12 meant, it's not comparable to my runtime one, that's why I asked. And yes, sounds like a good optimization to do. Good idea to test slices of 1 or 2.

Comment: @U12-Forward What would "remain in the same class instance"?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode ah I guess I misunderstood your comment about `+`, sorry about that.

Comment: @Masklinn No worries. Good idea with the slices, and [apparently](https://tio.run/##fcqxDsIgFIXhvU9xtoITtNEYYp@EMDSK9i5A7mXQp0ds4uLgP57zlVfdcprPhVu7ZwaBEnhNj6jM01rT025AT7DgurEijQPmfVpFIlco8SaABOJt0FgWKMIF0/Gkf5mzX@imP1R8vz8w5brjMBSmVNV4yymOurU3) this optimization is done for characters 0-255.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode makes sense, doing it for the entire unicode space seemed a bit much but I didn't test if the range was more restricted e.g. to just ascii or extended ascii. With that hint, it looks like those actually have their own special case just for them: when creating a string from a single byte (`Py_UCS1`), which is what `str.__getitem__` does internally but apparently not `str(1)`, the byte is looked up in the `latin1` array of the interpreter state, not even in the separate "interned string" cache.

Answer (score 0):

Since `str()` method is interpreted and run at the runtime (not at the compile time), python compiler does not know what `str(1)` is gonna be equal to. But basic string concatenation or definition of variable runs at the compile time, so the optimisation (string interning) can be made. See the below examples:

```
>>> a = '12'
>>> b = '1' + '2'
>>> c = str(12)
>>> d = ''.join(['1', '2'])

>>> a is b
True
>>> a is c
False
>>> b is c
False
>>> a is d
False
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found out that characters which match [a-zA-Z0-9_] are interned in Python

You "found out" wrong I fear.

Python automatically interns *string literals* as well as symbol names (e.g. module names, class names, method names, ...).

> And `str(1)` returns `'1'`, and I think, it should refers to the same address as other literal `'1'`s. Shouldn't `str(1)` is `'1'` also be `True`?

No. Interning is an explicit deduplication operation, and CPython *only exposes an API to intern a string*, there is not currently any way to intern a string if there's already an interned version without doing messing with the interpreter guts by hand.

This means if the output of `str()` could be interned (by `str` itself) it always would be, which is probably undesitable: while CPython does not "leak" interned strings (they don't leave forever), increasing the size of the interning map adds to its maintenance and management costs .