# String address in Python

Tags: python, string, types, memory-address

```py
str_1="Hello"
str_2="Hello"
print(str_1 is str_2)

str_3="Hello World"
str_4="Hello World"
print(str_3 is str_4)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

In the code snippet above, `str_1` and `str_2` have the same values and they share the same address in the memory. `str_3` and `str_4` also have the same values but they do not share the same address in the memory.

What might be reason behind this?

Comment: it got `true true`

Comment: this will help https://medium.com/@bdov_/https-medium-com-bdov-python-objects-part-iii-string-interning-625d3c7319de#:~:text=CPython%20stores%20strings%20as%20sequences,be%20of%20the%20same%20size.

Comment: I've voted to close this as "not reproducible". This will print `True` in both cases. If you want to update your question with more details (what version of Python? What OS?) such that we can reproduce the behavior you're describing we might be able to help out.

Comment: I also get `True` and `False` I'm using linux and I tried in python 3.7, 3.10

Comment: I can reproduce this on ubuntu 20 with python 3.8, and 2.7

Comment: I got the output from the jupyter notebook execution. Python version is `3.8.10`.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: @AlbinPaul Ubuntu 20

Comment: this answer will helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404661/9050514