# How to remove json element with empty quotes?

Tags: python, json

In the `python3` code below I read all the `objects` in the `json` then loop through the `elements` in the `json`. If I only search for the `id is not None` that element and the null value are removed. However when I add the `or` statement to remove the `id is not ""` the entire file is printed with neither of the `id` in the or statement removed. Being new to `python` I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you :).

**file**

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "version": "1",
        "list": [
            {
                "
                    "json": null
                },
                "id": "",
            }
        ],
        "h": "na"
    },
{
        "version": "1",
        "list": [
            {
                "
                    "json": null
                },
                "id": "This has text in it and should be printed",
            }
        ],
        "h": "na"
    },
{
        "version": "1",
        "list": [
            {
                "
                    "json": null
                },
                "id": null,
            }
        ],
        "h": "na"
    }
]
}
```

**desired**

```
{
        "version": "1",
        "list": [
            {
                "
                    "json": null
                },
                "id": "This has text in it and should be printed",
            }
        ],
        "h": "na"
    },
```

**python3**

```
if v["id"] is not None or v['id'] is not "":
```

Also tried the below and `id` were changed:

```
for obj in data['objects']:
if obj.get('id') is "":
    obj['description'] = 'na'
```

Comment: You want __`and`__ not __`or`__. Or `if v["id"] not in (None, "")`

Comment: Also this is relevant to your usage of `is` to check string equality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680240/843953

Comment: The JSON in the question is not valid syntax at all; it does not parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if v["id"] is not None or v['id'] is not "":
```

No matter what the value is, this statement will *always* be true.

If the value is None, then the `is not ""` part will be true.

If the value is an empty string, then the `is not None` part will be true.

And if the value is anything else, then both parts will be true.

As @Pranav commented, you want to use `and` here, not `or`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the explanation as I am learning :).